# SoftLayer API unable to get networkComponents in time after createObject

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

In the past, Using getObject method to get networkComponents(PrimaryBackendNetworkComponent, PrimaryNetworkComponent) in time after createObject.

The curl URL  is below with appropriate object mask.

```
$ curl 'https://{username}:{api_key}@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/{vid}.json?objectMask=mask%5Bid%2C+globalIdentifier%2C+hostname%2C+domain%2C+fullyQualifiedDomainName%2C+status.name%2C+powerState.name%2C+activeTransaction%2C+datacenter.name%2C+operatingSystem%5BsoftwareLicense%5BsoftwareDescription%5Bname%2Cversion%5D%5D%2Cpasswords%5Busername%2Cpassword%5D%5D%2C++maxCpu%2C+maxMemory%2C+primaryIpAddress%2C+primaryBackendIpAddress%2C+privateNetworkOnlyFlag%2C+dedicatedAccountHostOnlyFlag%2C+createDate%2C+modifyDate%2C+billingItem%5BnextInvoiceTotalRecurringAmount%2C+children%5BnextInvoiceTotalRecurringAmount%5D%5D%2C+notes%2C+tagReferences.tag.name%2C+networkVlans%5Bid%2CvlanNumber%2CnetworkSpace%5D%2C+primaryBackendNetworkComponent%5BprimaryIpAddress%2C+networkVlan%5Bid%2Cname%2CvlanNumber%2CprimaryRouter%5D%2C+subnets%5Bnetmask%2CnetworkIdentifier%5D%5D%2C+primaryNetworkComponent%5BprimaryIpAddress%2C+networkVlan%5Bid%2Cname%2CvlanNumber%2CprimaryRouter%5D%2C+subnets%5Bnetmask%2CnetworkIdentifier%5D%5D%5D'
```

And readable object mask is below:

```
INSTANCE_DETAIL_MASK = "id, globalIdentifier, hostname, domain, fullyQualifiedDomainName, status.name, " +
"powerState.name, activeTransaction, datacenter.name, " +
"operatingSystem[softwareLicense[softwareDescription[name,version]],passwords[username,password]], " +
" maxCpu, maxMemory, primaryIpAddress, primaryBackendIpAddress, " +
"privateNetworkOnlyFlag, dedicatedAccountHostOnlyFlag, createDate, modifyDate, " +
"billingItem[nextInvoiceTotalRecurringAmount, children[nextInvoiceTotalRecurringAmount]], notes, tagReferences.tag.name, networkVlans[id,vlanNumber,networkSpace], " +
"primaryBackendNetworkComponent[primaryIpAddress, networkVlan[id,name,vlanNumber,primaryRouter], subnets[netmask,networkIdentifier]], primaryNetworkComponent[primaryIpAddress, networkVlan[id,name,vlanNumber,primaryRouter], subnets[netmask,networkIdentifier]]"
```

But about 18 hours ago, This way is not working because two primary network components stay null. And I have to wait about 30 seconds to call in the workaround.

The question is that I want to know that this situation is temporary or permanent change. We programmatically request these API requests. So it is risky if not to find the root cause. 
Please tell me if anyone knows the details of Softlayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the createObject method does not create a Virtual server immediately, you need to check first if the server has been provisioned properly, for that propourse you can see the provisionDate property as it is detailed here: https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/phil/simplified-cci-creation Once the server has been provisioned properly you should be able to see all the information that you want to

Comment: Thank you. And I noticed that provision needs time. I guessed that 'provisionDate' will be set when the provision is complete.  May I ask you one question? Whether it will be modified again after provision?